# Converting day of month to how it is spoken without lookup table?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert Day of the Month to how a person would say it.

For instance 4/26 would be spoken as Twenty-Sixth.
4/01 would be spoken as First.

I know I could use a look up table string foo = {"First", "Second", ...}
then take the day of the Month number and pull out the string.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp

Comment: I know you said you don't want to use a lookup table, but my opinion is a couple `Dictionary<int, string>`s would be perfect.  One for Month, one for Day.

Comment: @Jeff month name is built in to the DateTime class already

Comment: @Muad'Dib Then even better, you should only need a 31 length dictionary for day.  ;)

Comment: How do you want to use it? Maybe an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes, you can encode the rules of English to produce ordinal numbers. However, the first nineteen words will inevitably end up in a lookup table, because they are exceptions.

In case of numbering days of the month, the range of exceptional values (1 through 19) covers roughly 60% of the total number of word sequences that you need to produce, so it would make sense to skip the algorithm altogether, and put everything in a lookup table. This would improve readability, and simplify internationalization in case you decide to support languages other than English.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way around a lookup table (even if it's provided by a third party). But you can reduce the number of cases:

- One entry for numbers 1-20 and 30 (as spoken in the date).
- The missing numbers can be combined, e.g. using 20 + 1, 20 + 2, 30 + 1, etc.