# How to convert currency amount to currency in words

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, currency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting numbers in to words C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp)

I am requiring an algorithm to convert currency amount to currency in words. The primary requirement is to have a generic algorithm so it takes culture information as a parameter along with the actual amount and display the amount in words accordingly and vice versa.

For example,

- Input: 1157259.50 (Ringgits - Malaysian Currency)
- Output: One Million One Hundred Fifty-Seven Thousand Two Hundred Fifty-Nine Ringgits and Fifty Cents

Comment: Currency symbol is availabe on CultureInfo, otherwise exact dup.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @FurqanSafdar Split the value into it's integer (Ringgits) and fractional (cents) portions, run each through the numbers to words algorithm them, append the currency names and add a conjunction ("and") in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the information but with due respect how to get the amount from the amount in words as i have mentioned in the body "vice versa"?

Comment: What about countries where money amounts are not divide in base of 3 digits, Japan for example 35486 its read: "san (three) man, go (five) sen, yon (four) hiaku, hachi (eight) yu, roku (six) en (yen)"?

Comment: @rsotolongo same for Chinese. I guess this kind of algorithm might be culture-specific.

Comment: @Guillaume I think so, but the given example is focused in western culture that **maybe** _simplify_ the problematic. Also there are currencies that are divided in more than two units. Everything depends of what the questioner wants and meybe he should specify more data and examples.

Comment: If the OP requires something culture-specific I think it worths reopning the question.