# Currency value to text representation - C#

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to convert a currency value I have (in UK pounds) into it's plain text representation. For example, I'd need to be able to convert this:

£399,994.71

To

Three Hundred and Ninety Nine Thousand, Nine Hundred and Ninety Four Pounds and Seventy One Pence

Is there anything in .NET that can do this for me? Or perhaps any existing code for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? I guess, there is no support from .NET

Comment: refer http://wiki.cdyne.com/index.php/Convert_Money_to_Text_in_C_Sharp

Comment: Have you searched about it?

Comment: Please see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b942f9/converting-numbers-to-words-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

I created this Gist, check it out:
https://gist.github.com/h22/5244967