# how to change decimal value (money) to string Value (money) on c#

Tags: c#

i just want to convert decimal value to string value 
for example  :
1.686.23
ONE MILION SIX HUNDRED EIGHTY SIX THOUSAND ...
how can i do it can you suggest an algorithm or example 
many thanks for your helps...

Comment: Answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635485/currency-value-to-text-representation-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user this method to get the string from numbers, it is working without the fraction (will not return 3.5 => three and half )

```
  public static string NumberToWords(int number)

{
    if (number == 0)
        return "zero";

    if (number < 0)
        return "minus " + NumberToWords(Math.Abs(number));

    string words = "";

    if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + " million ";
        number %= 1000000;
    }

    if ((number / 1000) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 1000) + " thousand ";
        number %= 1000;
    }

    if ((number / 100) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 100) + " hundred ";
        number %= 100;
    }

    if (number > 0)
    {
        if (words != "")
            words += "and ";

        var unitsMap = new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
        var tensMap = new[] { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

        if (number < 20)
            words += unitsMap[number];
        else
        {
            words += tensMap[number / 10];
            if ((number % 10) > 0)
                words += "-" + unitsMap[number % 10];
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```

Comment: many thanks  for helps , i am sorry i am new on this forum :)