# C# syntax error value expected

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I have these two line of code here

```
var unitsMap = new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
        var tensMap = new[] { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };
```

And I keep getting red squiggly error underline underneath both my `[]` saying syntax error value expected. and I also get a red squiggly error underline underneath all my values (one, two, three, etc) but not for zero...the error is ; expected.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just do a recompile. Nothing wrong with your code

Comment: What framework are you targeting?  This is an anonymous function declaration.  Make sure you are using a framework version that supports it.

Comment: You'll need to show all the code you have. The syntax error is likely coming from an earlier line.

Comment: I got the code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp

Comment: Ok that's where you got it, but we need to see _your_ code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Which version of .NET do you use?

Comment: ASP.NET I am using Visual Studio 2005

Comment: In that answer you reference those two arrays really should be defined as `static` in the class - otherwise, the arrays are instantiated every time the method is called which, based on the logic in that method, could be more than once since there is some recursion.

Comment: @KevinBrock Post it as an answer so that i can downvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using an older version of C# which doesn't support the var keyword, this was introduced in v3.0 and the minimum supported version of VS is 2008.

The equivalent in your version would be:

```
string[] unitsMap = { "zero", "one", ... };
srring[] tensMap = { "zero", "ten", ... };
```

Answer (score 2):

As David mentioned, you must be using a different framework which doesn't support anonymous declarations.

I just tried it using 4.5 framework and it doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

if "; is expected" maybe before these lines you have forgotten to end your previous line. Otherwise do a recompile. Sometimes, intellisense has to be rebooted (don't know why). Reboot VS if you will see this mistake again.