# Translation of Bangladesh currency to words

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 private string BDTtakatowords(Int64 BDTtaka)
 {
     string result="";
     if ((BDTtaka >= 1) && (BDTtaka <= 10))
     {
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 1) result = "One";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 2) result = "Two";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 3) result = "Three";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 4) result = "Four";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 5) result = "Five";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 6) result = "Six";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 7) result = "Seven";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 8) result = "Eight";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 9) result = "Nine";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Ten";
     }
     if (BDTtaka > 9 && BDTtaka < 20)
     {
         if (BDTtaka == 11) result = "Eleven";
         if (BDTtaka == 12) result = "Twelve";
         if (BDTtaka == 13) result = "Thirteen";
         if (BDTtaka == 14) result = "Forteen";
         if (BDTtaka == 15) result = "Fifteen";
         if (BDTtaka == 16) result = "Sixteen";
         if (BDTtaka == 17) result = "Seventeen";
         if (BDTtaka == 18) result = "Eighteen";
         if (BDTtaka == 19) result = "Nineteen";
        if (BDTtaka == 20) result = "Twenty";
     }
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 2 && (BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Twenty";
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 3 && (BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Thirty";
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 4 && (BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Forty";
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 5 && (BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Fifty";
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 6 && (BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Sixty";
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 7 && (BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Seventy";
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 8 && (BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Eighty";
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 9 && (BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Ninty";

     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 2 && (BDTtaka % 10) != 0)
     {
        if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 0) result = "Twenty";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 1) result = "Twenty One";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 2) result = "Twenty Two";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 3) result = "Twenty Three";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 4) result = "Twenty Four";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 5) result = "Twenty Five";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 6) result = "Twenty Six";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 7) result = "Twenty Seven";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 8) result = "Twenty Eight";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 9) result = "Twenty Nine";
     }
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 3 && (BDTtaka % 10) != 0)
     {
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 1) result = "Thirty One";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 2) result = "Thirty Two";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 3) result = "Thirty Three";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 4) result = "Thirty Four";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 5) result = "Thirty Five";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 6) result = "Thirty Six";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 7) result = "Thirty Seven";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 8) result = "Thirty Eight";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 9) result = "Thirty Nine";
     }
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 4 && (BDTtaka % 10) != 0)
     {
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 1) result = "Forty One";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 2) result = "Forty Two";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 3) result = "Forty Three";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 4) result = "Forty Four";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 5) result = "Forty Five";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 6) result = "Forty Six";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 7) result = "Forty Seven";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 8) result = "Forty Eight";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 9) result = "Forty Nine";
     }
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 5 && (BDTtaka % 10) != 0)
     {
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 1) result = "Fifty One";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 2) result = "Fifty Two";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 3) result = "Fifty Three";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 4) result = "Fifty Four";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 5) result = "Fifty Five";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 6) result = "Fifty Six";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 7) result = "Fifty Seven";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 8) result = "Fifty Eight";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 9) result = "Fifty Nine";
     }
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 6 && (BDTtaka % 10) != 0)
     {
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 1) result = "Sixty One";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 2) result = "Sixty Two";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 3) result = "Sixty Three";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 4) result = "Sixty Four";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 5) result = "Sixty Five";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 6) result = "Sixty Six";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 7) result = "Sixty Seven";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 8) result = "Sixty Eight";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 9) result = "Sixty Nine";
     }
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 7 && (BDTtaka % 10) != 0)
     {
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 1) result = "Seventy One";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 2) result = "Seventy Two";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 3) result = "Seventy Three";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 4) result = "Seventy Four";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 5) result = "Seventy Five";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 6) result = "Seventy Six";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 7) result = "Seventy Seven";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 8) result = "Seventy Eight";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 9) result = "Seventy Nine";
     }
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 8 && (BDTtaka % 10) != 0)
     {
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 1) result = "Eighty One";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 2) result = "Eighty Two";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 3) result = "Eighty Three";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 4) result = "Eighty Four";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 5) result = "Eighty Five";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 6) result = "Eighty Six";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 7) result = "Eighty Seven";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 8) result = "Eighty Eight";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 9) result = "Eighty Nine";
     }
     if (BDTtaka > 20 && (BDTtaka / 10) == 9 && (BDTtaka % 10) != 0)
     {
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 1) result = "Ninty One";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 2) result = "Ninty Two";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 3) result = "Ninty Three";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 4) result = "Ninty Four";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 5) result = "Ninty Five";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 6) result = "Ninty Six";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 7) result = "Ninty Seven";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 8) result = "Ninty Eight";
         if ((BDTtaka % 10) == 9) result = "Ninty Nine";
     }
     return result;
 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     TextBox2.Text = BDTtaka(Convert.ToInt64(TextBox1.Text));
 }
```

Problem: When I entry into Text1 like 20 or 20000 or 2000000 then show Taka only or Thousand   Taka only or   Lac  Taka only  respectively. But should show twenty or twenty thousand or twenty Lac respectively.

Comment: I am not able to answer your question because I do not really understand it perhaps because I lack knowledge about Bangladesh currency, but you would be better of if you replaced your convoluted (and also somewhat buggy) collection of if statements with a simple array of number words with 99 elements.

Comment: To our Bangladeshi currency is like: 1=one taka, 10=ten taka, 100=one hundred taka, 1000=one thousand taka, 99000=ninety nine thousand taka, 100000= one lac taka, 1000000=ten lac taka, 10000000=one crore taka

Comment: I've been tasked with maintaining code like this before.  For the sake of both your sanity and the sanity of your successors, please take the time to simplify this code.  Once you do that, I think you'll find that your question is much easier to answer, as it will be a natural extension of the pattern you've used to simplify the original approach.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question would be a better fit for CodeReview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly how you say it, but I'll give it a try:

```
//this array specifies the names of the powers of 10
static Tuple<int, string>[] powers =
{ 
    new Tuple<int, string>(0, ""),
    new Tuple<int, string>(3, "thousand"),
    new Tuple<int, string>(5, "lac"),
    new Tuple<int, string>(7, "crore")
};

//this array specifies the digits' names
static string[] digits = { "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };
static string[] extendedDigits = { "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fivteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
static string[] tensWords = { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

private static string NumberToWords(long number)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    //begin with the left most digit (greatest power of 10)
    for (int i = powers.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        //translate the current part only (for a known power of 10)
        //usually part is a 3-digit number
        int part = (int)(number / (long)Math.Pow(10, powers[i].Item1)); 
        //if the part is 0, we don't have to add anything
        if (part > 0)
        {
            //extract the hundreds
            int hundreds = part / 100;
            if(hundreds > 9)
                throw new ArgumentException(number + " is too large and cannot be expressed.");
            if (hundreds > 0)
            {
                //if there are hundreds, copy them to the output
                sb.Append(digits[hundreds]);
                sb.Append(" hundred ");
            }
            //convert the next two digits
            sb.Append(TwoDigitNumberToWord(part % 100));
            sb.Append(" ");
            //and append the name of the power of 10
            sb.Append(powers[i].Item2);
            sb.Append(" ");
            //subtract the currently managed part
            number -= part * (long)Math.Pow(10, powers[i].Item1);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

private static string TwoDigitNumberToWord(int number)
{
    //one digit case
    if (number < 10)
        return digits[number];
    //special case 10 <= n <= 19
    if (number < 20)
        return extendedDigits[number - 10];
    int tens = number / 10;
    int ones = number % 10;
    //concatenate the word from the two digits' words
    return tensWords[tens] + " " + digits[ones];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this into the wild (and ducking):

```
static string hundreds(Int64 n)
{
    n %= 100;
    switch (n)
    {
    case 0:
        return "zero";
    case 10:
        return "ten";
    case 11:
        return "eleven";
    case 12:
        return "twelve";
    case 13:
        return "thirteen";
    case 14:
        return "fourteen";
    case 15:
        return "fifteen";
    case 16:
        return "sixteen";
    case 17:
        return "seventeen";
    case 18:
        return "eighteen";
    case 19:
        return "nineteen";
    }

    string s = "";
    switch (n / 10)
    {
    case 2:
        s = "twenty";
        break;
    case 3:
        s = "thirty";
        break;
    case 4:
        s = "fourty";
        break;
    case 5:
        s = "fifty";
        break;
    case 6:
        s = "sixty";
        break;
    case 7:
        s = "seventy";
        break;
    case 8:
        s = "eighty";
        break;
    case 9:
        s = "ninety";
        break;
    }

    if (n/10 > 0 && n%10 > 0)
        s += " ";

    switch (n % 10)
    {
    case 1:
        s += "one";
        break;
    case 2:
        s += "two";
        break;
    case 3:
        s += "three";
        break;
    case 4:
        s += "four";
        break;
    case 5:
        s += "five";
        break;
    case 6:
        s += "six";
        break;
    case 7:
        s += "seven";
        break;
    case 8:
        s += "eight";
        break;
    case 9:
        s += "nine";
        break;
    }

    return s;
}

static string thousands(Int64 n)
{
    string s = "";
    int h = (int)(n%1000)/100;
    if (h > 0)
    {
        s += hundreds(h) + " hundred";
        int r = (int)n % 100;
        if (r == 0)
            return s;

        if (r > 0 && r < 10 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            s += " and ";
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && r > 0)
            s += " ";
    }
    return s + hundreds(n);
}

static string milionths(Int64 n)
{
    string s = "";
    int t = (int)(n%10000000)/1000;
    if (t > 0 && t < 100)
    {
        s += hundreds(t) + " thousand";
    }
    else
    {
        t /= 100;
        if (t > 0)
            s += hundreds(t) + " lac";
    }
    int r = (int)n % 1000;
    if (r == 0)
        return s;

    if (r > 0 && r < 10 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        s += " and ";
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && r > 0)
        s += " ";

    return s + thousands(n);
}

static string crore(Int64 n)
{
    string s = "";
    Int64 m = n/10000000;
    if (m > 0)
    {
        s += thousands(m) + " crore";
        int r = (int)n % 10000000;
        if (r == 0)
            return s;

        if (r > 0 && r < 10 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return s + " and one";
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && r > 0)
            s += " ";
    }
    return s + milionths(n);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(9999));
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(10000));
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(10100));
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(10101));
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(99999));
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(100000));
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(100001));
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(1000000));
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(10000000));
    System.Console.WriteLine(crore(10000001));

    System.Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It prints out:

```
nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine
ten thousand
ten thousand one hundred
ten thousand one hundred and one
ninety nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine
one lac
one lac and one
ten lac
one crore
one crore and one
```

Answer (score -1):

This may(?) answer your question. It appears you're trying to do the same thing, just in a much more convoluted way. [converting numbers in to words C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp)