# Count the characters in a cookie string using c#

Tags: c#

Count the characters in a cookie string using c#

I have a string as follows:

```
string str1 = Request.Cookies["GE"].Value;
```

This string could be:

```
string str1 = "A";
```

or

```
string str1 = "AA";
```

or

```
string str1 = "AABB";
```

Using C#, I need to display the count of character as follows:

```
string str1 = "A"; ===> One
string str1 = "AA"; ===> Two
string str1 = "AABB"; ===> Four
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check below link of possible answer

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp

Comment: Are you looking for the verbal representation as [Bat_Programmer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/475709/) suggested or just [`string.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an integer value use

```
Request.Cookies["GE"].Value.Length
```

If you need the value in words then make reference to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp) provided by Bat_Programmer.