# How to convert int to string in c#

Tags: c#

Please help how do I convert int to string. For example

```
int num = 9;
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("X"));
```

Will display

> 9

Expected Output:

> 9 = nine

Comment: It's not a conversion of `int` to `string`, but more like [numbers to text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2729752/1997232).

Comment: sounds like homework

Comment: To convert int to string use:    myInteger.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

So you want to write "nine" not "9"?

In the former case you'll have to use a selection statement, preferably switch/case.

eg

```
int num = 9
string stringNum;
switch (num)
{
    case 9:
        stringNum = "nine";
        break;
}
```

In the latter case, you can just print the integer.

```
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Comment: *Latter* is what OP already doing. Can you demonstrate `switch/case` example in you answer? Otherwise it's too short for an answer (basically a suggesting comment without *real* solution).

Comment: I added switch example code.