# Can someone help me with this python programming problem create a program that will convert integer to string?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Can someone help me with this python programming problem
create a program that will convert integer to string
example
input number: 999
result: nine hundred 99

input number: 1
result: one

input number: 22
result: twentytwo

Comment: Please provide examples that you have tried and what is the issue so we could help you to resolve the issue. Please see on how to ask a questions here in stackoverflow.com -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting numbers in to words C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [num2words](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/) library in Python. For example:

```
from num2words import num2words
print(num2words(12))
```

Output:

```
twelve
```

Answer (score 0):

First do

```
$ pip install inflect
```

then do

```py
    import inflect
    p = inflect.engine()
    p.number_to_words(99)
```