# How to convert number to words in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Can anyone teach me how to convert numbers to words? For example:

```
18,000.00
```

In words:

```
eighteen thousand
```

Hope anyone can help. I am using Visual Studio 2008 professional edition.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation

Answer (score 0):

High level algorithm:

```
Break the number into three-digit groups
For each group {
    if value > 0 {
        Compute string translation
        output string + group identifier (eg. million, thousand, etc)
    }
}
```

The three-digit translation step would need to examine the hundreds digit and out it's string equivalent + " hundred and " if it's greater than 0.  The remaining two digits could be used to index into a string array if < 20, or handled separately to index string arrays for each digit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic developed by [Justin Rogers](http://weblogs.asp.net/Justin_Rogers/archive/2004/06/09/151675.aspx):

```
using System;

public class NumberToEnglish {
    private static string[] onesMapping = 
        new string[] {
            "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
            "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen",
            "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"
        };
    private static string[] tensMapping =
        new string[] {
            "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", 
            "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"
        };
    private static string[] groupMapping =
        new string[] {
            "Hundred", "Thousand", "Million", "Billion", "Trillion"
        };

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(EnglishFromNumber(long.Parse(args[0])));
    }

    private static string EnglishFromNumber(int number) {
        return EnglishFromNumber((long) number);
    }

    private static string EnglishFromNumber(long number) {
        if ( number == 0 ) {
            return onesMapping[number];
        }

        string sign = "Positive";
        if ( number < 0 ) {
            sign = "Negative";
            number = Math.Abs(number);
        }

        string retVal = null;
        int group = 0;
        while(number > 0) {
            int numberToProcess = (int) (number % 1000);
            number = number / 1000;

            string groupDescription = ProcessGroup(numberToProcess);
            if ( groupDescription != null ) {
                if ( group > 0 ) {
                    retVal = groupMapping[group] + " " + retVal;
                }
                retVal = groupDescription + " " + retVal;
            }

            group++;
        }

        return sign + " " + retVal;
    }

    private static string ProcessGroup(int number) {
        int tens = number % 100;
        int hundreds = number / 100;

        string retVal = null;
        if ( hundreds > 0 ) {
            retVal = onesMapping[hundreds] + " " + groupMapping[0];
        }
        if ( tens > 0 ) {
            if ( tens < 20 ) {
                retVal += ((retVal != null) ? " " : "") + onesMapping[tens];
            } else {
                int ones = tens % 10;
                tens = (tens / 10) - 2; // 20's offset

                retVal += ((retVal != null) ? " " : "") + tensMapping[tens];

                if ( ones > 0 ) {
                    retVal += ((retVal != null) ? " " : "") + onesMapping[ones];
                }
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir. . How will i apply this codes above. ??   this is my Form.. Textbox1 is equal to number,  then Label1 is the in words of equivalent of number in textbox1 . my question where will i put this codes i mean the codes that you send me. . pls help sir. .

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for all numeric values up to the specified limit for floating-point operations in VB and VBA.

All numbers exceeding one 'trillion' are recursed: quadrillions and quintillions are expressed in the form 'One thousand, nine hundred and six trillion' and whatever trivial quantity of billions, millions, thousands, hundreds, tens and digits remains to be accounted in petty cash.

You can therefore express 2<sup>50</sup> as:

Eleven Hundred and Twenty-Five Trillion, Eight Hundred and Ninety-Nine Billion, Nine Hundred and Six Million, Eight Hundred and Forty-Two Thousand, Six Hundred and Twenty
One Trillion, Ninety-Nine Billion, Five Hundred and Eleven Million, Six Hundred and Twenty-Seven Thousand, Seven Hundred and Seventy-Six

I do not anticipate that you will need to express this kind of number in text on a regular basis. However, there is some instructional value in demonstrating an application of recursion to beginners in programming.

```
Public Function SayNumber(ByVal InputNumber As Double, Optional DecimalPlaces As Integer = 0) As String
```

' Return the integer portion of the number in formatted English words

' Return the fractional part of the number as 'point' and a series of
' single-numeral words, up to the precision specified by 'DecimalPlaces'

'   SayNumber(17241021505)
'   "Seventeen Billion, Two Hundred and Forty-One Million, Twenty-One Thousand, Five Hundred and Five"

'   SayNumber(Sqr(2), 6)
'   "One point Four One Four Two One Four"

' Note that nothing after the decimal point will be returned if InputNumber is an integer

' Nigel Heffernan, December 2008

Application.Volatile False
On Error Resume Next

Dim arrDigits(0 To 9)   As String
Dim arrTeens(10 To 19)  As String
Dim arrTens(2 To 9)     As String

Dim i            As Integer
Dim i10          As Integer
Dim i20          As Integer
Dim dblRemainder As Double
Dim dblMain      As Double
Dim iRemainder   As Long
Dim iMain        As Long
Dim dblFraction  As Double
Dim strFraction  As String

Dim strMinus     As String
Dim str1         As String
Dim str2         As String
Dim str3         As String

If Application.EnableEvents = False Then
    Exit Function
End If

arrDigits(0) = "Zero"
arrDigits(1) = "One"
arrDigits(2) = "Two"
arrDigits(3) = "Three"
arrDigits(4) = "Four"
arrDigits(5) = "Five"
arrDigits(6) = "Six"
arrDigits(7) = "Seven"
arrDigits(8) = "Eight"
arrDigits(9) = "Nine"
            
arrTeens(10) = "Ten"
arrTeens(11) = "Eleven"
arrTeens(12) = "Twelve"
arrTeens(13) = "Thirteen"
arrTeens(14) = "Fourteen"
arrTeens(15) = "Fifteen"
arrTeens(16) = "Sixteen"
arrTeens(17) = "Seventeen"
arrTeens(18) = "Eighteen"
arrTeens(19) = "Nineteen"

arrTens(2) = "Twenty"
arrTens(3) = "Thirty"
arrTens(4) = "Forty"
arrTens(5) = "Fifty"
arrTens(6) = "Sixty"
arrTens(7) = "Seventy"
arrTens(8) = "Eighty"
arrTens(9) = "Ninety"

If InputNumber < 0 Then
    strMinus = "Minus "
    InputNumber = Abs(InputNumber)
End If

If DecimalPlaces < 1 Then
    strFraction = ""
Else

dblFraction = InputNumber - Fix(InputNumber)
    If dblFraction = 0 Then
        strFraction = ""
    Else
        strFraction = " point"
        str1 = Format(dblFraction, "0." & String(DecimalPlaces, "0"))
        For i = 1 To DecimalPlaces
            str2 = MID(str1, i + 2, 1)
            strFraction = strFraction & " " & arrDigits(CInt(str2))
            str2 = ""
        Next i
        str1 = ""
    End If
    
End If

If InputNumber < 10 Then

str1 = arrDigits(InputNumber)
    
ElseIf InputNumber < 19 Then

str1 = arrTeens(InputNumber)
    
ElseIf InputNumber < 100 Then
    
    iMain = InputNumber \ 10
    str1 = arrTens(iMain)
    
    iRemainder = InputNumber Mod 10
    If iRemainder > 0 Then
        str2 = "-" & arrDigits(iRemainder)
    End If

ElseIf InputNumber < 1000 Then

iMain = InputNumber \ 100
    str1 = arrDigits(iMain) & " Hundred"
    
    iRemainder = InputNumber Mod 100
    If iRemainder > 0 Then
        str2 = " and " & SayNumber(iRemainder)
    End If
    
ElseIf InputNumber < 2000 Then

iMain = InputNumber \ 100
    str1 = arrTeens(iMain) & " Hundred"
    
    iRemainder = InputNumber Mod 100
    If iRemainder > 0 Then
        str2 = " and " & SayNumber(iRemainder)
    End If
    
ElseIf InputNumber < 1000000 Then

iMain = InputNumber \ 1000
    str1 = SayNumber(iMain) & " Thousand"

iRemainder = InputNumber Mod 1000
    If iRemainder > 0 Then
        str2 = ", " & SayNumber(iRemainder)
    End If
    
ElseIf InputNumber < (10 ^ 9) Then

iMain = InputNumber \ (10 ^ 6)
    str1 = SayNumber(iMain) & " Million"

iRemainder = InputNumber Mod (10 ^ 6)
    If iRemainder > 0 Then
        str2 = ", " & SayNumber(iRemainder)
    End If
    
ElseIf InputNumber < (10 ^ 12) Then  ' we'll hit the LongInt arithmetic operation limit at ~2.14 Billion

str3 = Format(InputNumber, "0")
    dblMain = CDbl(Left(str3, Len(str3) - 9))
    str1 = SayNumber(dblMain) & " Billion"
    
    dblRemainder = CDbl(Right(str3, 9))
    If dblRemainder > 0 Then
        str2 = ", " & SayNumber(dblRemainder)
    End If
        
ElseIf InputNumber < 1.79769313486231E+308 Then       ' This will generate a recursive string of 'Trillions'

str3 = Format(InputNumber, "0")
    dblMain = CDbl(Left(str3, Len(str3) - 12))
    str1 = SayNumber(dblMain) & " Trillion"
    
    dblRemainder = CDbl(Right(str3, 12))
    If dblRemainder > 0 Then
        str2 = ", " & SayNumber(dblRemainder)
    End If
        
Else ' exceeds the specification for double-precision floating-point variables

str1 = "#Overflow."
        
End If

SayNumber = strMinus & str1 & str2 & strFraction

End Function

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer:

```
Sub M_snb()
    MsgBox F_snb(InputBox(String(4, vbLf) & "enter a number", "snb")), , "snb"
End Sub

Function F_snb(y)
    F_snb = "invalid input"
    If y = 0 Then F_snb = "zero"
    If y = "" Or Val(y) = 0 Then Exit Function

    c00 = Format(Val(1 * y), String(3 * ((Len(Format(Val(1 * y))) - 1) \ 3 + 1), "0"))

    For j = 1 To Len(c00) \ 3
        x = Mid(c00, 3 * (j - 1) + 1, 3)

        sp = Array(F_mats(Left(x, 1)), F_mats(Val(Right(x, 2))), F_mats(Right(x, 1)), F_mats(Mid(x, 2, 1) & "0"), F_mats(Mid(x, 2, 1)))
        c01 = c01 & IIf(sp(0) = "", "", sp(0) & " Hundred ") & IIf(Right(x, 2) = "00", "", IIf(sp(1) <> "", sp(1), IIf(Mid(x, 2, 1) = "1", Trim(sp(2)) & "teen", IIf(sp(3) = "", sp(4) & "ty", sp(3)) & " " & sp(2)))) & Choose(Len(c00) \ 3 - j + 1, "", " Thousand ", " Million ", " Billion ")
    Next

    F_snb = Trim(Replace(c01, "  ", " "))
End Function

Function F_mats(y)
    On Error Resume Next

    F_mats = Split(Split(" 0 1One 2Two 3Three 4Four 5Five 6Six 7Seven 8Eight 9Nine 10Ten 11Eleven 12Twelve 13Thirteen 15Fifteen 20Twenty 30Thirty 40Forty 50Fifty 80Eighty ", y)(1))(0)
End Function
```