# Numbers to words using arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to make a simple number to english words program and I've decided to use arrays. However whenever I enter a number greater than 99, I get an error in the third if clause.. What do I need to change to fix that? Here's my code;

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         string[] uptonineteen = {"Zero","One","Two","Three","Four",
        "Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten",
        "Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen",
        "Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"};
        string[] ten = {"","","Twenty","Thirty","Forty","Fifty",
        "Sixty","Seventy","Eighty","Ninety",};
        Console.WriteLine(" ---------------");
        int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (i < 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(uptonineteen[i]);
            }
            if (i < 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ten[i / 10] + ((i % 10 > 0) ? "" + uptonineteen[i%10] : ""));
            }
            if (i <= 999)
            {
                object lenthree = ten[i / 100] + "hundred"+" " + ((i % 100 > 0) ? "and" +" "+  uptonineteen[i % 1000] : "");
                Console.WriteLine(lenthree);
            } 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Also, why are you doing i % 1000 ? shoudl it not be i % 100 ?

Comment: "index was out of the bounds of the array".. i think it happens when i try to do  <code>ten[i / 100]</code> and yeah noticed that and edited it but i still get the same error

Comment: Even `i % 100` can yield numbers > 19.

Comment: It dosen't solve the fact that the program still doesn't give the proper output, but uptonineteen[i % 1000] needs to be uptonineteen[i % 10].

Comment: @DannyPetrunov See a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation/71742126#71742126

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this too many times... This one handles, such as doing check writing and you may need to go into millions, thousands and includes cents at the end...

```
public class NumToWords
{
    public NumToWords()
    {}

    string[] OneToNineteen = 
        { "zero",   
          "one",    "two",    "three",    "four",     "five",    "six",     "seven",     "eight",    "nine",   "ten",   
          "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };

    // empty string for zero-place-holder for tens grouping
    string[] Tens = { "", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

    // leave blank for "hundreds" because you would NOT do 123 as One hundred twenty-three hundred.
    string[] Block3Section = { "", "thousand", "million", "billion" };


    public string ToEnglish(int num)
    {
        int Block3Seq = 0;
        int curSegment;
        int tmp;
        string FinalWords = "";
        string curWord = "";

        while (num > 0)
        {
            curSegment = num % 1000;    // get only 3 digits worth (right) of the number
            num = (num - curSegment) / 1000;  // subtract this portion from the value

            if (curSegment > 0)
            {
                // always add the closing word as we HAVE something to build out
                curWord = "";

                // how many "hundreds" of the current segment
                tmp = (int)curSegment / 100;
                if (tmp > 0)
                    curWord += " " + OneToNineteen[tmp] + " hundred";

                // what is remainder of this 100 based segment
                tmp = curSegment % 100;

                if (tmp < 20)
                    curWord += " " + OneToNineteen[tmp];
                else
                {
                    curWord += " " + Tens[(int)tmp / 10]
                                + '-' + OneToNineteen[tmp % 10];
                }

                // always add the closing word as we HAVE something to build out
                curWord += " " + Block3Section[Block3Seq];

                // add the section above to the overall words
                FinalWords = curWord + FinalWords;
            }

            // to allow the next closing word for segment such as thousand, million, billion, etc
            Block3Seq++;
        }

        return FinalWords;
    }

}
```

Comment: @DannyPetrunov, I've completely revised original post but using modulus % as you were originally attempting to do.

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation/71742126#71742126

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] uptonineteen = {"Zero","One","Two","Three","Four",
        "Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten",
        "Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen",
        "Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"};
        string[] ten = {"", "","Twenty","Thirty","Forty","Fifty",
        "Sixty","Seventy","Eighty","Ninety",};
        Console.WriteLine(" ---------------");
        int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (i < 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uptonineteen[i]);
        }
        else if (i < 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((((i % 100) / 10) > 1) ? ten[((i % 100) / 10)] + ((i % 10) > 0 ? " " + uptonineteen[(i % 10)] : "") : " and " + uptonineteen[i % 100]));
        }
        else if (i <= 999)
        {
            object lenthree = uptonineteen[(i % 1000) / 100] + " hundred " + ((((i % 100) / 10) > 1) ? ten[((i % 100) / 10)] + ((i % 10) > 0 ? " " + uptonineteen[(i % 10)] : "") : " and " + uptonineteen[i % 100]);
            Console.WriteLine(lenthree);
        } 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string lenthree = ten[i / 100] + "hundred" + " " + 
    ((i % 100 > 0) ? "and" + " " + uptonineteen[i % 100] : "");
```

The last 1000 should be 100. But since your `uptonineteen` isn't full, you still can't enter full numbers correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After handling a case `number > x` you should continue with the remainder `number = number % x` or `number %= x` which is the same. Also you should really make the distinction between getting the English text and doing tests on the console. `Console.WriteLines` and `Console.ReadKeys` should not appear withing the logic. Build the English string using a `StringBuilder` by using this general structure:

```
public static string ToEnglish(int number)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (number >= 100) {
        ...
        number %= 100;
    }
    if (sb.Length > 0 && number != 0) {
        sb.Append("and ");
    }
    if (number >= 20) {
        ...
        number %= 10;
    }
    if (sb.Length == 0 || number != 0) {
        ...
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note: I don't post a complete solution since I assume its homework.

---

The console test looks like this

```
while (true) {
    Console.Write("Please enter a number or `q` to quit: ");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    if (s == "q") {
        break;
    }
    int i = int.Parse(s);
    Console.WriteLine(ToEnglish(i));
}
```

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation/71742126#71742126

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] ones = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", 
                            "eleven", "twelve", "thirtheen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen","nineteen", "twenty" };
string[] tens = { "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirthy", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"};

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (i < 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ones[i]);
        }
        if (i > 30  & i < 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tens[((i%100)/10)-1]+ " " + ones[(i % 10)]);
        }
        if (i > 100 & i < 1000)
        {
            if (((i % 100) % 10) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ones[(i / 100)] + " hundred " + tens[((i % 100) / 10) - 1]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ones[(i / 100)] + " hundred " + tens[((i % 100) / 10) - 1] + " and " + ones[((i % 100) % 10)]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Hello there trademark, next time provide a little explanation for you code instead of just posting it