# vb.net srgsgrammar trigger any number

Tags: vb.net, winforms, speech-recognition

I am trying to use speech recognition to trigger reco.speechrecognized events on ANY number announcement

currently I have had success with using dictionary

```
    reco.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()

    Dim gram As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsDocument

    Dim callRule As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("numbers)

    Dim termList As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")

    callRule.Add(termList)

    gram.Rules.Add(callRule)

    gram.Root = callRule

    reco.LoadGrammar(New Recognition.Grammar(gram))

    reco.RecognizeAsync()
```

obviously that would be horrible to create an entire dictionary of 0 to 5000

then operating a recognition sub

```
Private Sub reco_SpeechRecognized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognitionEventArgs) Handles reco.SpeechRecognized

Select Case e.Result.Text
    Case "one"
        'action
    Case "two"
        'action
    'etc
End select

End sub
```

I ideally want to fire these events regardless of what number was spoken.  I essentially would need a statement to replace the select

```
if e.Result.Text (is a number) then
    'number
else
    'some other command
end if
```

is there a better way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able convert a bunch of numbers to text using the answers to the following question.  Using the strings you should be able to add these strings into your grammer.

[How can I convert an integer into its verbal representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/554314/1757491)

[converting numbers in to words C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp)