# Convert Numerical Digits in Vocabulary Forms

Tags: c#

How can I convert final amount of billing to it's related vocabulary form?

I am trying to develop a function which convert it in vocabulary form.

For, ex. 12345 Rs. then it's output should be like this

TWELVE THOUSAND THREE HUNDRED N FORTY FIVE ONLY

is it possible with few easy steps in C# ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation

Comment: You should manually implement it like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2730393/4063639

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use an external library, i'd suggest you try out [Humanizer](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer)

Really simply to use and your example would be as simple as.

```
12345.ToWords(); //it adds extension methods that achieve this.
```