# How can I write SQL SELECT statement to convert numbers into their words

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my table:

```
ENAME   SALARY
AAAA    $1254.20
GGGG    $4565
RRRR    $7889.60
WEFDSF  $0.00
XXXX    N/A
```

I want that salary to be display in words, for eg: 1254.20 should be displayed as one thousand two hundred fifty four dollars and twenty cents

Comment: Any attempt at it yourself that you could share?

Comment: I don't think it's a job for an SQL query, better implement it in the representation layer.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I tried with - SELECT ENAME,TO_CHAR((SALARY),'$9,999.99') SALARY, TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (1254, 'j'), 'jsp') AS TO_WORDS
FROM T1

Comment: Try [How can I convert an integer into its verbal representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation) you can get logic out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a hack for integers using conversion to julian date: [HOW TO:  Spell a number or convert a number to words](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3650?start=0&tstart=0)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (1234567, 'j'), 'jsp') FROM DUAL;
```

You can split `SALARY` into integer dollars and cents and apply the hack:

```
Select
  TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (Dollars, 'j'), 'jsp') || ' dollars ' ||
  TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (Cents, 'j'), 'jsp') || ' cents' As Spelling
From (
  Select
    TRUNC(1254.20) As Dollars,
    (1254.20 - TRUNC(1254.20)) * 100 As Cents
  From DUAL);
```

Admittedly you also need to cover for single dollar / cent.
Best be done in a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spell_amount
  (srcAmnt IN NUMBER)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  Dollars INT;
  Cents INT;
  Result VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  Dollars := Trunc(srcAmnt);
  Cents := Trunc((srcAmnt - Dollars)*100);

  IF Dollars = 0 THEN
    Result := 'no dollars';
  ELSIF Dollars = 1 THEN
    Result := 'one dollar';
  ELSE
    Result := TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (Dollars, 'j'), 'jsp') || ' dollars';
  END IF;

  IF Cents = 0 THEN
    Result := Result || ' no cents';
  ELSIF Cents = 1 THEN
    Result := Result || ' one cent';
  ELSE
    Result := Result || ' ' || TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (Cents, 'j'), 'jsp') || ' cents';
  END IF;

  RETURN Result;
END spell_amount;
/
```

And then

```
Select spell_amount(132.01) From DUAL;
```

Some more on `ORA-01854: julian date must be between 1 and 5373484` limitation of Julian date and possible solution: [How To Convert Number into Words using Oracle SQL Query](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-number-into-words-oracle-sql-query/)

And [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65a029/1)

Answer (score 0):

Substitute 12345.15 with your column name and remove $ sign from the column before substitution.

select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(floor(12345.15),'J'),'JSP')||'  Dollars '|| case
 when 12345.15 - FLOOR(12345.15)>0 then 'And '||TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(substr('12345.15',instr('12345.15','.')+1),'J'),'JSP') || ' Cents'
 end INWORDS
from dual;