# Number Translator up to 999999999 to Words

Tags: c#, numbers

I'm trying to make a number translator that will work on any number up to
999999999 and translate that into a string representation.

input = 999999999 
output = Nine Hundred Ninety Nine Million Nine Hundred Ninety Nine Thousand, Nine Hundred Ninety Nine

Any help on a better way to handle this will be appreciated.

Full disclosure i have used a lot of ideas
from this previous solution.

[converting numbers in to words C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

   int inputNumber;



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Translate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (int.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out inputNumber) )
        {
            TranslateNumber();
        }

    }

    private void TranslateNumber()
    {

        var unitsMap = new[] { " ", " One ", " Two ", " Three ", " Four ", " Five ", " Six ", " Seven ", " Eight ", " Nine ", " Ten ", " Eleven ", " Twelve ", " Thirteen ", " Fourteen ", " Fifteen ", " Sixteen ", " Seventeen ", " Eighteen ", " Nineteen " };
        var tensMap = new[] { " ", " Ten ", " Twenty ", " Thirty ", " Forty ", " Fifty ", " Sixty ", " Seventy ", " Eighty ", " Ninety " };


        if (inputNumber == 0)
        {
            tBlkOutput.Text += "zero";
        }




        if ((inputNumber / 100000000 ) > 0)
        {
            // needs a number betwwen 1 and 9
            tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 100000000] + " Hundred Million ";
            inputNumber %= 100000000;
        }

        if ((inputNumber / 1000000) > 0 )
        {
            // need to be able to list between 1 million and 99 million
            if ((inputNumber / 10000000) > 0)
            {
                tBlkOutput.Text += tensMap[inputNumber / 10000000];
                inputNumber %= 10000000;
            }
            if ((inputNumber / 1000000) > 0)
            {
                tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 1000000];
                inputNumber %= 1000000;
            }

            tBlkOutput.Text += " Million ";
        }
        if ((inputNumber / 100000) > 0)
        {
            // needs a number betwwen 1 and 9
            tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 1000000] + " Hundred Thousand ";
            inputNumber %= 1000000;
        }

        if ((inputNumber / 10000) > 0)
        {
            if ((inputNumber / 100000) > 0)
            {
                tBlkOutput.Text += tensMap[inputNumber / 10000];
                inputNumber %= 10000;
            }
            if ((inputNumber / 1000) > 0)
            {
                tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 1000];
                inputNumber %= 1000;
            }
            tBlkOutput.Text += " Thousand ";
        }

        if ((inputNumber / 100) > 0)
        {
            tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 100] + " Hundred and ";
            inputNumber %= 100;
        }
        if ((inputNumber / 10 ) > 0)
        {
            tBlkOutput.Text += tensMap[inputNumber / 10];
            inputNumber %= 10;
        }
        if (inputNumber > 0)
        {
            tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber];
        }



    }

    private void Reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tBlkOutput.Text = "";
        inputNumber = 0;
        txtInput.Text = "";
        txtInput.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This C# code.

1. Create a class and name it what ever you want. in my case **JayClass** then write following custom visual basic functions as shown.

   ```
      public class  JayClass
      {

       public static object Choose(double index,params object[] choice)
        {

        if (index < 1 || index > choice.Length)
        {
            return " ";
        }
        else
        {
            return choice[Convert.ToInt32(--index)];
        }

    }

     public static string Mid(string input, int start, int length)
    {
        string temp = input.Substring(start-1,length);
        return temp;
    }

     public static string Mid(string input, int length)
    {

        string temp = input.Substring(length);
        return temp;
    }

     public static string Left(string input , int length)
    {

        string temp = input.Substring(0,length);
        return temp;
    }

     public static string Right(string input, int length)
    {

        string temp = input.Substring(input.Length-length, length);
        return temp;
    }

    public static string Format(object Exprs, string style = "")
    {

        string temp = String.Format("{0:"+style+"}",Exprs);
        return temp;
    }
    }
   ```
2. create another class and name what ever you want, in my case **Trillion** and write the below methode within the class. Yes, "Trillion" because it can translate numeric digits from one up to trillion to words.

```
public class Trillion{

 public static string GET_Trillion(double value)
{
   String[] M = new String[9], L = new String[10], K = new String[8], Place = new String[5];
            String PN, Results = "";
            // ONES IN WORDS
            M[0] = "one";
            M[1] = "two";
            M[2] = "three";
            M[3] = "four";
            M[4] = "five";
            M[5] = "six";
            M[6] = "seven";
            M[7] = "eight";
            M[8] = "nine";

            // TENS IN WORDS
            L[0] = "ten";
            L[1] = "eleven";
            L[2] = "twelve";
            L[3] = "thirteen";
            L[4] = "fourteen";
            L[5] = "fifteen";
            L[6] = "sixteen";
            L[7] = "seventeen";
            L[8] = "eighteen";
            L[9] = "nineteen";

            K[0] = "twenty";
            K[1] = "thirty";
            K[2] = "forty";
            K[3] = "fifty";
            K[4] = "sixty";
            K[5] = "seventy";
            K[6] = "eighty";
            K[7] = "ninety";
            PN = "and ";

            // placement
            Place[0] = " hundred ";
            Place[1] = " thousand ";
            Place[2] = " million ";
            Place[3] = " billion ";
            Place[4] = " trillion ";

            if (value.ToString().Length> 15)
            {
                 throw new Exception(
                        "OutOfRangeException\nMessage: Please consider setting a value not greater than 15 digits. "
                                + value.ToString().Length + (value.ToString().Length > 1 ? " digits Keyed" : " digit Keyed"));

            }
            if (value.ToString().Length < 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                       "OutOfRangeException\nMessage: Please consider setting a value atleast  not less than one(1) digit  "
                                + value.ToString().Length + (value.ToString().Length <-1 ? " digits Keyed" : " digit Keyed"));

            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 14, 1)) != 1)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 15, 1)) + 1, "", M[0],
                        M[1], M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]);
            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 15, 1)) + 1, L[0], L[1],
                        L[2], L[3], L[4], L[5], L[6], L[7], L[8], L[9]);
            }

            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 14, 1)) > 1
                    && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 15, 1)) > 0)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 14, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + "-" + Results;

            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 14, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + Results;
            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 13, 1)) == 0)
            {

            }
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 14, 1)) == 0
                  && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 15, 1)) == 0)
            {

                Results = Place[0];
            }
            else
            {
                Results = Place[0] + PN + Results;
            }
            Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                    Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 13, 1)) + 1, "", M[0], M[1],
                    M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]) + Results;

            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 10, 1)
                    + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 11, 1)
                    + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 12, 1)) == 0)
            {

            }
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 13, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 14, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 15, 1)) == 0
                  || Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 13, 1)) != 0)
            {
                Results = Place[1] + Results;

            }
            else
            {
                Results = Place[1] + PN + Results;

            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 11, 1)) != 1)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 12, 1)) + 1, "", M[0],
                        M[1], M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]) + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 12, 1)) + 1, L[0], L[1],
                        L[2], L[3], L[4], L[5], L[6], L[7], L[8], L[9]) + Results;
            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 11, 1)) > 1
                    && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 12, 1)) > 0)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 11, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + "-" + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 11, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + Results;
            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 10, 1)) == 0)
            {

            }
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 11, 1)) == 0
                  && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 12, 1)) == 0)
            {
                Results = Place[0] + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = Place[0] + PN + Results;
            }
            Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                    Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 10, 1)) + 1, "", M[0], M[1],
                    M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]) + Results;

            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 7, 1)
                    + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 8, 1)
                    + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 9, 1)) == 0)
            {
            }
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 10, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 11, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 12, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 13, 1)) == 0
                  && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 14, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 15, 1)) > 0)
            {
                Results = Place[2] + PN + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = Place[2] + Results;
            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 8, 1)) != 1)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 9, 1)) + 1, "", M[0], M[1],
                        M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]) + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 9, 1)) + 1, L[0], L[1],
                        L[2], L[3], L[4], L[5], L[6], L[7], L[8], L[9]) + Results;

            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 8, 1)) > 1
                    && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 9, 1)) > 0)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 8, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + "-" + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 8, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + Results;
            }

            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 7, 1)) == 0)
            {

            }
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 8, 1)) == 0
                  && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 9, 1)) == 0)
            {
                Results = Place[0] + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = Place[0] + PN + Results;
            }
            Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                    Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 7, 1)) + 1, "", M[0], M[1],
                    M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]) + Results;
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 4, 1)
                    + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 5, 1)
                    + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 6, 1)) == 0)
            {

            }
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 7, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 8, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 9, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 10, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 11, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 12, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 13, 1)) == 0
                  && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 14, 1)
                          + JayClass.Right(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 1)) > 0)
            {
                Results = Place[3] + PN + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = Place[3] + Results;
            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 5, 1)) != 1)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 6, 1)) + 1, "", M[0], M[1],
                        M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]) + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 6, 1)) + 1, L[0], L[1],
                        L[2], L[3], L[4], L[5], L[6], L[7], L[8], L[9]) + Results;
            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 5, 1)) > 1
                    && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 6, 1)) > 0)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 5, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + "-" + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 5, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + Results;
            }

            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 4, 1)) == 0)
            {
            }
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 5, 1)) == 0
                  && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 6, 1)) == 0)
            {
                Results = Place[0] + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = Place[0] + PN + Results;
            }
            Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                    Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 4, 1)) + 1, "", M[0], M[1],
                    M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]) + Results;
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Left(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 1)
                    + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 2, 1)
                    + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 3, 1)) == 0)
            {
            }
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 4, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 5, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 6, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 7, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 8, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 9, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 10, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 11, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 12, 1)
                          + JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 13, 1)) == 0
                  && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 14, 1)
                          + JayClass.Right(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 1)) > 0)
            {
                Results = Place[4] + PN + Results;

            }
            else
            {
                Results = Place[4] + Results;
            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 2, 1)) != 1)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 3, 1)) + 1, "", M[0], M[1],
                        M[2], M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]) + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 3, 1)) + 1, L[0], L[1],
                        L[2], L[3], L[4], L[5], L[6], L[7], L[8], L[9]) + Results;
            }

            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 2, 1)) > 1
                    && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 3, 1)) > 0)
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 2, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + "-" + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                        Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 2, 1)) + 1, "", "", K[0],
                        K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6], K[7]) + Results;
            }
            if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Left(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 1)) == 0)
            {
            }
            else if (Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 2, 1)) == 0
                  && Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Mid(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 3, 1)) == 0)
            {
                Results = Place[0] + Results;
            }
            else
            {
                Results = Place[0] + PN + Results;
            }

            Results = (String)JayClass.Choose(
                    Convert.ToDouble(JayClass.Left(JayClass.Format(value, "000000000000000"), 1)) + 1, "", M[0], M[1], M[2],
                    M[3], M[4], M[5], M[6], M[7], M[8]) + Results;

            return Results;
        }

    }
```

Assuming you input this number, **"9,999,999,999,999"** it will be translated to words exactly like this **"nine trillion nine hundred and ninety-nine billion nine hundred and ninety-nine million nine hundred and ninety-nine thousand nine hundred and ninety-nine"**

Use it and thank me later.

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation/71742126#71742126

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where i was going wrong, put some if statements where they needed to be and now it works for the most part.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

   int inputNumber;



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Translate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (int.TryParse(txtInput.Text, out inputNumber) )
        {
            TranslateNumber();
        }

    }

    private void TranslateNumber()
    {

        var unitsMap = new[] { " ", " One ", " Two ", " Three ", " Four ", " Five ", " Six ", " Seven ", " Eight ", " Nine ", " Ten ", " Eleven ", " Twelve ", " Thirteen ", " Fourteen ", " Fifteen ", " Sixteen ", " Seventeen ", " Eighteen ", " Nineteen " };
        var tensMap = new[] { " ", " Ten ", " Twenty ", " Thirty ", " Forty ", " Fifty ", " Sixty ", " Seventy ", " Eighty ", " Ninety " };


        if (inputNumber == 0)
        {
            tBlkOutput.Text += "zero";
        }






        if ((inputNumber / 1000000) > 0 )
        {
            if ((inputNumber / 100000000) > 0)
            {
                // needs a number betwwen 1 and 9
                tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 100000000] + " Hundred and ";
                inputNumber %= 100000000;
            }

            // need to be able to list between 1 million and 99 million
            if ((inputNumber / 10000000) > 0)
            {
                tBlkOutput.Text += tensMap[inputNumber / 10000000];
                inputNumber %= 10000000;
            }
            if ((inputNumber / 1000000) > 0)
            {
                tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 1000000];
                inputNumber %= 1000000;
            }

            tBlkOutput.Text += " Million ";
        }


        if ((inputNumber / 1000) > 0)
        {
            if ((inputNumber / 100000) > 0)
            {
                // needs a number betwwen 1 and 9
                tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 100000] + " Hundred and  ";
                inputNumber %= 100000;
            }

            if ((inputNumber / 10000) > 0)
            {
                tBlkOutput.Text += tensMap[inputNumber / 10000];
                inputNumber %= 10000;
            }
            if ((inputNumber / 1000) > 0)
            {
                tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 1000];
                inputNumber %= 1000;
            }
            tBlkOutput.Text += " Thousand ";
        }

        if ((inputNumber / 100) > 0)
        {
            tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber / 100] + " Hundred and ";
            inputNumber %= 100;
        }
        if ((inputNumber / 10 ) > 0)
        {
            tBlkOutput.Text += tensMap[inputNumber / 10];
            inputNumber %= 10;
        }
        if (inputNumber > 0)
        {
            tBlkOutput.Text += unitsMap[inputNumber];
        }



    }

    private void Reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tBlkOutput.Text = "";
        inputNumber = 0;
        txtInput.Text = "";
        txtInput.Focus();
    }
}
```