# issue with conversion of amount, from numbers to character

Tags: c#, numbers, string-formatting

I'm trying to convert an amount from numbers to string. While converting `3070` to `three thousand seventy only` I noticed a flaw in the code, the output is supposed to be `three thousand seventy only` but instead of this the output is `Three Thousand  Rupees only`.

I got the code from the internet,

When i debug the code, I see the following lines

```
if ((rupees / 1000) > 0)
        {
            res = rupees / 1000;
            rupees = rupees % 1000;
            result = result + ' ' + rupeestowords(res) + " Thousand";
        }
```

The problem arises in this code because `1010,1020,.....,3070,3080,3090,4010,4020.etc` all the numbers are % to 1000, that means if I enter these number the output will be wrong,

I am unable to get the proper logic here. I think i need to validate the rupees again inside another if condition.

Code below X Thousands

```
 if ((rupees / 100) > 0)
        {
            res = rupees / 100;
            rupees = rupees % 100;
            result = result + ' ' + rupeestowords(res) + " Hundred";
        }
        if ((rupees % 10) > 0)
        {
            res = rupees % 100;
            result = result + " " + rupeestowords(res);
        }
        result = result + ' ' + " Rupees only";
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to add the following conversion as well.
rupeestowords(rupees )

Comment: will you help me to resolve this??

can you show me the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert an integer into its verbal representation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation)

Comment: This can't be the whole code... The error must be in the brachen if((rupees / 100) > 0) or more likely in if ((rupees /10) > 0)

Comment: You've posted the code that does the x Thousand bit which is working fine.  Post the code that does the tens (seventy) bit, or in fact just post all of it.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
if ((rupees % 10) > 0)
{
    res = rupees % 100;
    result = result + " " + rupeestowords(res);
}
```

This line is wrong:

```
res = rupees % 100;
```

Should be

```
res = rupees / 10;
```

Also the following line is wrong:

```
if ((rupees % 10) > 0)
```

Should be:

```
if ((rupees / 10) > 0)
```

Leaving:

```
if ((rupees / 10) > 0)
{
    res = rupees % 10;
    result = result + " " + rupeestowords(res);
}
```

Comment: still not going inside the loop

Comment: editing my answer, there's another incorrect line - you chose some bad code to use

Comment: now i am getting

 Three Thousand Five  Rupees only

when my input is 3050

Comment: Changed answer again - you could be doing this yourself of course  Should be: res = rupees / 10;