# Convert number into string in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

In french , 1(one) is said as `un` , what i want to do is as soon as i want to convert a number to a string . For example,if the number(integer) is `1` then the result would be `un` , how to achieve this ?

Comment: Please be more specific. WHat type of number. What is the required format.

Comment: `1234` , can this be converted to `Hello` ?? How can u expect a number to become a word and even FRENCH!! ...However , to get an integer as string just use `myinteger.ToString`

Comment: @zack raiyan hope it is 1 = "one" (eng) = "un" (french)

Comment: try to look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation

Comment: please approve my edit to make it clear for others to understand

Comment: To be more specific i want the format to fill in a check. For example: 1200 will be converted as "Mille deux cent"

Comment: `if (myint ==1) { string result = "un" }`

Comment: @zackraiyan but when i have big integers how to do?

Comment: `if (myint ==1200) { string result = "Mille deux cent" }`

Comment: I wnat that that will be done automatically not to a specific numbers!

Comment: It can't happen automatically, what you can do is create a text file for all the number(in frech),read it and store it in a list, and then use the list :)

Answer (score 0):

A more specific question would be more helpful. But I'm going to take a guess you mean something like the following. Unfortunately there's no built-in special formatting tricks to handle the singular case.

```
   string text = number == 1 ? "un" : number.ToString();
```

You might also be interested in a formatting library like Pluralizer:
http://www.jasonq.com/blog/2011/introduction-to-a-string-pluralizer-for-net

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in English, as my French isn't perfect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LanguageNumberConverter
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        var input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var result = NumberConverter(input);

        Console.WriteLine($"The number {input} = {result}.");
    }

    static string NumberConverter(int number)
    {
        var resultWords = new List<string>();
        var chars = number.ToString().ToCharArray();

        var largeCount = (chars.Length - 1) / 3;

        for (var l = largeCount; l >= 0; l--)
        {

            var searchRange = chars.Length - (l * 3);
            var digitStart = searchRange - 3 > 0 ? searchRange - 3 : 0;
            var digitsInLarge = l == largeCount ? chars.Length % 3 : 3;
            var teenFound = false;

            //Hundreds
            if (digitsInLarge > 2)
            {
                var hunDigit = int.Parse(chars[digitStart].ToString());
                resultWords.Add(Ones[hunDigit]);
                resultWords.Add("Hundred");
            }

            //Tens
            if (digitsInLarge > 1)
            {
                var tenDigit = int.Parse(chars[digitStart + digitsInLarge - 2].ToString());
                if (tenDigit == 1)
                {
                    teenFound = true;
                    var teenDigit = (tenDigit * 10) + int.Parse(chars[digitStart + digitsInLarge - 1].ToString());
                    resultWords.Add(Ones[teenDigit]);
                }
                else
                {
                    resultWords.Add(Tens[tenDigit]);
                }
            }

            //Ones
            if (!teenFound)
            {
                var oneDigit = int.Parse(chars[digitStart + digitsInLarge - 1].ToString());
                resultWords.Add(Ones[oneDigit]);
            }

            //Large
            if (l > 0)
            {
                var unit = Large[l];
                resultWords.Add(unit);
            }
        }

        var result = "";
        foreach (var word in resultWords)
        {
            result += word + " ";
        }
        return result.Trim();
    }

    static string[] Ones =
    {
        "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine",
        "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen",
        "Eighteen", "Nineteen"
    };

    static string[] Tens =
    {
        "Zero", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy",
        "Eighty", "Ninety"
    };

    static string[] Large =
    {
        "Zero", "Thousand", "Million", "Billion", "Trillion"
    };
}
```

}